# Does Chucky give the middle finger right before he dies after getting shot in the heart in Child's Play (1988)?

Tags: childs-play

Does Chucky give the middle finger right before he dies after getting shot in the heart in Child's Play (1988)?  It looks like it but I don't know if that was the intention of the filmmakers.  At around 0:57 of this clip.

Comment: It raises its index finger, I don’t see the middle finger move at all.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot likewise thats all I saw

Comment: Dead wrong.  He does give the middle finger.

Comment: @aosuh83 Except the scene at .25x speed shows he doesn't. He extends his index finger, not his middle finger.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 dead wrong.  He gives the middle finger.

Comment: @aosuh83 So provide evidence to support your claim. A timestamp in the video would be nice, or a still of the doll flipping them the bird.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 the video shows Chucky giving them the finger

Comment: Can I ask, what's the point of asking this question if you're going to blatantly disagree with any answers or thoughts provided?

Comment: @Möoz - Looking to confirm their own fan-theory

Comment: @Möoz Trolling. I've seen this exact MO on Movies.SE at least a dozen times before.

Comment: To be fair, it's possible that the finger he moves after his hand hits the floor might be the middle one.

Answer (score 4):

The [original script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/childs-play-1988.pdf) indicates that he just died. No final salute is given.

> **CHUCKY:** *No, don't shoot me. I'm your friend to the end, remember.*
>
> 225: INT. LIVING ROOM - NIGHT
>
> **KAREN:** *Yeah, sure. And this is the end, friend!…*
>
> She pulls the trigger, the bullet blowing a hole in Chucky's chest
> right where his human heart is. **Blood flies as the doll slams back
> against a wall and sinks to the ground, dead, smoke still rising off
> his charred body.**
>
> 226   INT. HALLWAY - NIGHT In the hallway, Chucky's head speaks one last
> time.
>
> **CHUCKY:** *I love you. Hidey ho, ha-ha-haaaaaaa*
>
> It runs down like a broken record ending in silence. The eyes slam
> shut one last time, Jack staring at it in horror.

Note also that it's not his middle finger that's extended, it's his forefinger

[image]

Comment: Dead wrong.  He does give the middle finger.

Comment: @aosuh83 - If you can back that up, it would make a great answer.